# bash find command for counting files does not work

Tags: bash, find

I tried to count files with the find command:

```
echo "0" > ct
find aaaa/ -type f -exec expr $(cat ct) + 1 > ct \;
cat ct
1
1
1
1
```

If I execute it manually, it works propely:

```
echo "0" > ct
expr $(cat ct) + 1 > ct
expr $(cat ct) + 1 > ct
expr $(cat ct) + 1 > ct
expr $(cat ct) + 1 > ct
cat ct
4
```

Comment: Try it with `{} \;` instead of just `\;`

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that the shell parses and applies `$(cat ct)` and `> ct` before running `find`, so you're effectively running `find aaaa/ -type f -exec expr 0 + 1 \; > ct`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it like this:

```
find aaaa/ -type f -exec printf '%.s.' {} + | wc -c
```

Or if GNU find is available:

```
find aaaa/ -type f -printf '.' | wc -c
```

But if you insist on going with your logic -even though it's not effective or practical-, you need to do the command substitution and redirection in a shell (see [Gordon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337116/bash-find-command-for-counting-files-does-not-work/58337373#comment103031205_58337116)), e.g:

```
echo 0 > ct
find aaaa/ -type f -exec sh -c 'expr "$(cat ct)" + 1 > ct' \;
cat ct
```

With this approach, 3 processes (sh, cat, expr) for each file is spawned, and a file is created, and then updated n times where n is the number of files, which is a big waste of memory and CPU time.
At least you could've used bulk exec like:

```
echo 0 > ct
find aaaa/ -type f -exec sh -c 'expr "$(cat ct)" + "$#" > ct' _ {} +
cat ct
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem lies in the fact that **exec** of the find command treats the **'>'** redirection as **'>>'** in consecutive calls.
Thus

```
find aaaa/ -type f -exec echo "xxxx" > file.txt \;
```

works as:

```
echo "xxxx" > file.txt
echo "xxxx" >> file.txt
...
echo "xxxx" >> file.txt
```

The workaround is using the **sh** (as oguz ismail proposed):

```
find aaaa/ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "xxxx" > file.ct' \;
```